# Uploading/synchronizing with development server

Tags: eclipse, synchronization, development-environment

I am working on a windows machine using eclipse and I would like to automatically upload of sync the changed files with my virtual server (using linux). I've used unison, but having to type in my password for every change is tedious.

What tools would you use?